# Creating a Moodle 2 theme

Tags: php, themes, moodle

I've created a new Moodle Theme, just as Moodle's documentation suggests.

In the config.php file I defined the layouts just like this:

```
$THEME->layouts = array(
    // Most pages - if we encounter an unknown or a missing page type, this one is used.
    'base' => array(
        'theme' => 'nop',
        'file' => 'general.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post'
    ),
    'standard' => array(
        'theme' => 'nop',
        'file' => 'general.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post'
    )
);
```

After creating it I selected it in the Moodle's admin zone, and cleand cache. In the admin-theme select page I can see this theme colours, styles and new interface, but, in the other regions of the Moodle (every other pages) I don't see it.

Does anybody know why is this weird this happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve it by adding this code in the config.php file.

```
$THEME->layouts = array(    // Most pages - if we encounter an unknown or a missing page type, this one is used.
    'base' => array(
        'theme' => 'nop',
        'file' => 'general.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post'
    ),
    'standard' => array(
        'theme' => 'nop',
        'file' => 'general.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post'
    ),
    'frontpage' => array(
        'theme' => 'nop',
        'file' => 'general.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post'
    ) );
```